# Possible to recreate the labeled geometry example on an animated mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm interested in if it would be possible to reproduce the [Labeled Geometry](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html) three.js example on an animated asset, and if so, how?

I want to attach labels to an animated 3D model but they do not move along with the asset (even if I parent them to it) I'm guessing because the animation performs a mesh deformation itself.

Is there a performant way to have, say, the sprite's position reference that of a specific vertex in the animated mesh buffer? Something that would not require me to manually update the sprite's position whenever the mesh's animation progresses. Ideally I would like to parent the sprite to a particular face or vertex on the mesh, but as far as I know there is no way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What kind of animation are you using? Morph target or skeletal animation?

Comment: Hmm, how would the answer differ per animation type?

Comment: Morph target or skeletal animation happens on the GPU. If you want to assign a label to a specific vertex position, you need to perform the respective computations on the CPU via JavaScript. This procedure depends on the respective animation type.

Comment: If the animation occurs on the GPU, can I still access the updated vertex positions from the CPU javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You have to compute the necessary information with JavaScript.